# Script to compare Oracle Schema with Teradata Views

Tags: oracle, compare, view, teradata

I have a task to compare some Teradata Views with actual Oracle Tables.
I need a script for that.I have taken Java approach in which I connect to a specific schema from Oracle and then call the `SELECT * FROM all_tables order by TABLE_NAME` query and write this into a file.
I do the same for other schema but now my problem is Teradata.
Can you people please suggest me some script or query by which I can get proper details like it does with Oracle.

There is no complex Java Code but if you still want I can post it.

Edited:

Okay now I have a schema in Oracle which has all the tables.so views for those tables are created in Teredata.
I have to compare oracle tables and Teradata views every morning and send the differances.
So I use `SELECT * FROM all_tables order by TABLE_NAME` in Oracle and for Teradata I use `SELECT * FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind='V' AND databasename='SCHEMA' order by TableName` so now when I compare them I dont get accurate results, so I wanted to know does any script exists or how do I approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is "How can I programmatically determine the structure of a view in Teradata?", then this should be a step in the right direction: `HELP VIEW yourviewname;`.

To get a list of views on a given table:

```
SELECT TableName
FROM DBC.Tables
WHERE Tablekind = 'V'
AND requestText LIKE '%yourtablename%'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

This information was gleaned from the [official Teradata forums](http://forums.teradata.com/).  You might also be interested in the [Teradata users manuals](http://www.info.teradata.com/Datawarehouse/eBrowseBy.cfm?page=TeradataDatabase). (Select your release version on the top right.)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply but can you please elaborate `requestText LIKE '%yourtablename%'`.

Comment: The query that I use for Teradata is 
`SELECT * FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind='V' AND databasename='SCHEMANAME'order by TableName;`
But still I don't get accurate results.

Comment: What kind of information do you need? What are the "proper details" and "accurate results" you're expecting? Most of the columns returned by all_tables simply don't have a counterpart in Teradata

Comment: Okay now I have a schema in Oracle which has all the tables.so views for those tables are created in Teredata.
I have to compare oracle tables and Teradata views every morning and send the differances.
So I use `SELECT * FROM all_tables order by TABLE_NAME` in Oracle and for Teradata I use `SELECT * FROM dbc.tables WHERE tablekind='V' AND databasename='SCHEMA' order by TableName` so now when I compare them I dont get accurate results, so I wanted to know idoes any script exists or how do I approach.

Comment: Again, what is "I dont get accurate results"? What do you get and what do you want? Do you just want to compare the names of the views/tables or the columns or what?

Comment: When I fire the query I get all the table details like its last access time, row counts in Oracle `all_tables` attributes but it is very different with Teradata `dbc.tables ` attributes.
So I am asking is there any query or script which compares both of them or do I need to write the whole script and if yes, can anyone please suggest me query which gives same kind of attributes so I just need to compare the details.
I am sorry if I am confusing.